# How to upload a website developed in asp.net using c# in linux server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux

I am developing a web application using Asp.net and c# in .Net 2008. So can we upload this web application in a Linux server. If so then kindly guide me with the necessary steps to upload this application ASAP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @mnagel..... can u plzz brief me on use of Mono... is it possible using it..

Comment: is like trying to make a flash game for the ps3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about both Mono and Apache, as you will probably use the mod_mono approach,

http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Make sure you finish the FAQ page,

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET

Answer (score -1):

.net framework only works under Windows platform according to Microsoft.

If you want to run a web-based application in Linux, please use java or php.

Comment: That's not true. Via Mono, ASP.NET apps can run fine on other platforms.